# Distinguish \columnsep for twocolumn and wrapfigure

Tags: spacing, two-column, wrapfigure

As far as I understand, the length `\columnsep` is used both for the gap between columns in a `twocolumn` document and for the space around a `wrapfigure`.

How can I change the space between columns, but control the space around my figure independently?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
  \rule{4cm}{4cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: before `\begin{document}` control columns sep after it control `wrapfigure` sep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

`\columnsep` in preambl control the column sep.

`\columnsep` after `\begin{document}` control the `wrapfigure` sep.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{wrapfig}


\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
  \rule{4cm}{4cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, with this solution, if you at some point in the document exit two-column mode and re-enter it afterwards, your column separation will suddenly be 50pt.